# linux system problem

Tags: linux

very first thanks to u all for Ur support.
I'm quite new to Linux .i know how to install software but i don't know
1: how to install library .a or .so files
i: how to install tar.gz i use the method like ./configure. make make install but most of the time i got the message nothing to make .in lots of tar.gz there is no installation document no make file no .configure file that make me quite confused how to install them or run them

now i got sample source code of cuda i got them in tar.gz form when i extract them i found a folder in folder i found folder like c ,doc,shared etc when i open each folder i found more folder n file like that src, doc common ,lib, in these folder i found source code file header files libraries file make files

i don't know how to run this kind of project can the be installed on the system 
how to run them they don't have .run file or script they don't have configure file 
can any one explain me how to compile them ,how to run them & how to install them

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Linux I suggest you install software by installing packages using the package manager. Different distributions of Linux use different packagae managers.

For Ubuntu - check the [documentation for installing software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware)

After a few months you may be familiar enough with your distribution to install software directly using tar, gunzip, make and other lower level tools. Personally I don't because I appreciate the benefits of having the package manager know about all the software on the system.